# Bootstrap (Twitter) Datepicker Difference Calculation Returns "NaN"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Following code returns "NaN" (Not a Number) value on change date. Flow is correct I think but I couldn't figure out how it returns a NaN.

```
$(function() {    
$('.datepicker').datepicker({format: "yyyy-mm-dd"});

    var calculateDuration = function() {
    var start_date = $('#start_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var end_date = $('#end_date').datepicker('getDate');
    document.getElementById('reservation_duration').value = (Number(end_date) - Number(start_date)) / 86400000;
    }

$('#end_date').change(calculateDuration);
$('#start_date').change(calculateDuration);

});
```

This is the datepicker: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.datepicker('getDate')` isn't a valid method. You probably just want the field's value, e.g., `$('#start_date').val()`

**UPDATE**
You still need to convert your field value into a format suitable for arithmetic:

```
var startDate = new Date($('#start_date').val());
var endDate = new Date($('#end_date').val());
var delta = endDate - startDate;
```

Comment: Well you'll need to convert the string to a suitable value. Simply casting a datestamp such as `07/05/2013` the way you're trying to do it will return `NaN`: `console.log(Number('07/05/2013'))`

Comment: You're absolutely right on the money. I've added the working code as an answer in this thread. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17492274/1589850) THANK YOU SO MUCH! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Followed André Dion's suggestion and made it work!**

```
$(function() {    
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({format: "yyyy-mm-dd"});

var calculateDuration = function() {
    var startDate = new Date($('#start_date').val());
    var endDate = new Date($('#end_date').val());
    var diff = endDate - startDate;
    document.getElementById('reservation_duration').value = (Number(diff) / 86400000) +1;
}

$('#end_date').change(calculateDuration);
$('#start_date').change(calculateDuration);

});
```